# document object confusion

Tags: php, html, dom

In `file1.php`, I execute `file2.php` with

```
<form action="file2.php" method="POST">
```

Within file2, I want to access html elements from file1, but their document objects are different.

How can I access file1's elements from within file2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well rather then using javascript you can access what you need via PHP's [$_POST](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) function so if you had the elements name and password you could access them with:

```
$_POST['name'];
$_POST['password'];
```

so something like this for file2.php:

```
<?php
    if(array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))
    {
        $username = $_POST['name'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        echo("Hello $username, your password is $password");
    }
?>
```

That goes on the assumption of file1.php looking like:

```
<form action="file2.php" method="post">
    Username:
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <br />
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: great, this was the answer I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try hiding in file2.php the elements that you still need?.

Just render them again with php in file2.php, and hide them via CSS, then they will be easily accesible through javascript.